# How can I attach dynamic details of a custom Spring Boot health indicator to a micrometer Gauge

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator, spring-micrometer

In spring boot I can add a custom HealthIndicator like

```kotlin
class MyHealthIndicator(): AbstractHealthIndicator{
  public override fun doHealthCheck(builder: Health.Builder){
    if (true) {
      builder.down()
      builder.withDetail("Details", "{\"reason\":\"Bad proxy\"}")
     } 
  }
}
```

And I can convert this custom health indicator to a metric using Mirometer like

```kotlin
@Configuration(proxyBeanMethod = false)
class HealthMetricExporterConfig(registry: MeterRegistry, healthEndpoint: HealthEndpoint){
  init {
    val compositeHealth = healthEndpoint.health() as CompositeHealth

    compositeHealth.components.forEach {
     Gauge.builder("health.${it.key}", it.key) { key -> 
       statusToNumber(healthEndpoint.healthForPath(key).status)
     }
     .strongReference(true)
     register(registry)
    }
 }

 private fun statusToNumber(status: Status): Double {
   return when(status) {
     Status.UP -> 3.0
     Status.DOWN -> 2.0
     Status.OUT_OF_SERVICE -> 1.0
     else -> 0.0
   }
 }
}
```

I know that I can add Tags to my Gauge to show the details of my health indicator (the JSON in MyHealthIndicator). But as the docs related to register method of the Builder class

> each registry is guaranteed to only create one gauge for the same combination of name and tags

[Gauge.builder.register()](https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/micrometer/blob/edc3289511ec5c5e5a504be20d1a5d85b45f931b/micrometer-core/src/main/java/io/micrometer/core/instrument/Gauge.java#L188C79-L190C25)

If I use the `tags` to add the details of my `MyHealthIndicator`, once the detail changes The gauge in `HealthMetricExporterConfig` cannot update it. It will stay the same as it was at the creation of the Gauge

The metrics will be scraped into Prometheus. I'm using Grafana to visualize them.

My question is, how can I also show the details (JSON) of this Gauge while I'm showing its value?